# Is it possible to prompt ChatGPT into playing a competent game of hangman?

Tags: chatgpt, prompt-design, games

I asked [ChatGPT](https://poe.com/ChatGPT) the following (some of the back-and-forth is omitted for space reasons):

> Can you play hangman?
> Can you think of a word?
> E

And ChatGPT was like:

> Great guess! There is one "e" in the word.
>
> _ _ _ _ _ e_

So seven letters, okay.  And after many guesses...

> Sorry, but there is no "k" in the word. Here's the updated status of the hangman figure:
> +---+
> | |
> O |
> /|\ |
> | |
> / |
>
> Please guess again! Here's the current word:
>
> _ o t asne_ r

and we're now up to 9 letters, and then finally

> Sorry, but there is no "m" in the word. Here's the updated status of the hangman figure:
> +---+
> | |
> O |
> /|\ |
> | |
> / \ |
>
> Oh no, that was the final incorrect guess! The word we were looking for was "potatoes".
>
> Thanks for playing hangman with me! Feel free to start a new game or ask me anything else you'd like to know.

Clearly ChatGPT is struggling with playing hangman here.  So...

**Question**: Is it possible to prompt ChatGPT into playing a competent game of hangman?

Comment: Given that ChatGPT is proprietary and secret, this question may not be answerable. A similar question for GPT-2 (proprietary, but public), or an open model, would be answerable.

Comment: A positive answer should be fine for any model, subject to a bit of randomness. A negative answer would probably need inner workings, which might be possible using theoretical considerations, or maybe an open model; but either way I have no idea how such an answer would come about...

Comment: The key point of this question is understanding what exactly "stateful" means for chatGPT. In order to be able to play a game it should either: a) decide the word and then play from here. This is not a problem for how a normal application operates, but I doubt chatGPT alone can maintain this type of internal state, b) play like Absurdle does - no set word but every new answer has to be in the realm of possible solution at that point of the game (see: [absurdle](https://qntm.org/absurdle) ) and again I doubt chatGPT can do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several issues likely at play:

1. The only state ChatGPT's LLM has is what's visible in the chat history. It can't internally keep track of a word that it selected at the start, so would have to guess what the word might be during each generation.

One way around this may be to use the web interface's message formatting syntax to have the model output a word in a format that you can't immediately see, such as the alt text on an image:

[image: Getting ChatGPT to hide a word in an image's alt text]

Giving it a simpler instruction first, then adding details once it obeys that, seems to help avoid it objecting to the instructions ("As an LLM I can't display images", etc.)

2. LLMs are trained on tokens, which are [approximately 4 characters long](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/4936856-what-are-tokens-and-how-to-count-them). The model may see "Potatoes" as `[25396, 15048]` but the letters individually as `[47, 267, 256, 257, 256, 267, 304, 264]`. In many cases the model will have learned some associations for what individual-letter tokens are contained in a word-piece token, but there's no direct link between the two forms so it may still struggle with tasks that require treating a word as its individual letters (e.g: reversing text).

As it needs to be aware of the individual letters to make the game work, having it initially output the hidden word as I N D I V I D U A L letters, so it can see each character separately, should help.

3. For a similar reason, with it seeing text as a tokens rather than 2D graphics, it won't be great at ASCII art. However, Hangman drawings are likely common enough for it to memorise. I think the problem here is just that whitespace is being collapsed.

Asking it to put the drawing in a code block appears to solve this issue:

[image: Correct hangman drawing and explanation]

4. LLMs often struggle with consistency over long conversations, and will forget entirely after their max token limit (4096, for GPT-3.5-turbo used by the free version of ChatGPT). Hangman's repeated back-and-forth, particuarly with the ASCII art, could make it lose track of the hidden word and its instructions.

It should help to ask it to repeat the hidden word at the start of each message. I also decided to compromise by replacing the hangman diagram for a shorter "Lives" counter.

Below is a screenshot (continued from the first image in this answer) for a game that worked as intended, combining the adjustments above:

[image: Successful full game]

Be aware that it can still be unreliable, often spoiling the game by telling you the word, or making mistakes in what letters it reveals.